# Start setInterval on hover and stop on mouseout

Tags: setinterval

I am trying to start a `setInterval` loop on hover an pause / stop it on mouseout. The mouseout works, but the loop starts initially not only on hover.

```
// Loop trough a set of images
var loop = setInterval(function(){
  rotator.src = dir + num+'.jpg';
  num = (num === len) ? 0 : ++num;
}, delayInMilliseconds);


// The loop should only start on hover
$( '#rotator' ).hover(

  function() {
    console.log( 'hover' );
  },

  // The loop should stop on mouseout
  function() {
    clearInterval( loop );
    console.log( 'no hover' );
  }

)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var interval = null;

function animatedCode() {
  rotator.src = dir + num+'.jpg';
  num = (num === len) ? 0 : ++num;}

//Stop and start on hover
$('#rotator').hover(function() {
  interval = window.setInterval(function(){animatedCode()},delayInMilliseconds);

}, function() {
  window.clearInterval(interval);
});
```